# What is the Linux command to store variables in text file

Tags: linux, shell, command

I want to store some variables in `.txt` file
but the code below saves only the last variable.
How do I fix it?

```
$x1 ="a"
$x2 = "b"
$x3 = "c"

>myfile.txt
echo $x1 >myfile.txt
echo $x2 >myfile.txt
echo $x3 >myfile.txt
```

Comment: use `>>` to append the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` is "create-or-replace file, write output". You want `>>`, which is "open file for appending"

```
echo $x1  >myfile.txt  # create/overwrite file
echo $x2 >>myfile.txt  # append to file
echo $x3 >>myfile.txt  # append to file again
```

Answer (score 2):

```
COMMAND_OUTPUT >
      # Redirect stdout to a file.
      # Creates the file if not present, otherwise overwrites it.

COMMAND_OUTPUT >>
      # Redirect stdout to a file.
      # Creates the file if not present, otherwise appends to it.
```

[**tldp documentation on I/O redirection**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

```
#writes the variables to the files
x1="a"
x2="b"
x3="c"

echo $x1 >> myfile.txt
echo $x2 >> myfile.txt
echo $x3 >> myfile.txt
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't empty the file before starting the writing, whereas the question did do that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (least learning) is to use `>>` to append to the file:

```
>myfile.txt
echo $x1 >>myfile.txt
echo $x2 >>myfile.txt
echo $x3 >>myfile.txt
```

You could omit the echo-less line and use just `>` instead of `>>` to get the same effect, but there is some merit to the consistency shown above.

Another way to do it is with the I/O grouping operators, [`{` and `}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping):

```
{
echo $x1
echo $x2
echo $x3
} > myfile.txt
```

And another way is to send all standard output to the file from here onwards, using [`exec`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) in combination with [I/O Redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections):

```
exec >myfile.txt
echo $x1
echo $x2
echo $x3
```

If you need to get switch standard output back to the original, you have to preserve it first:

```
exec 3>&1 >myfile.txt
echo $x1
echo $x2
echo $x3
exec 1&>3 3>&-
```

The `3>&1` notation opens file descriptor 3 as a copy of file descriptor 1 (standard output).
The `1>&3` notation opens file descriptor 1 (standard output) as a copy of file descriptor 3 (created just before).  The `3>&-` notation closes file descriptor 3.